# Robospice SpiceException cannot be resolved

Tags: android, robospice

I imported the project to eclipse and got these errors:

```
The type com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.exception.SpiceException cannot
be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

and

```
The import com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.DurationInMillis cannot be
resolved
```

[image]

I think it is missing java build path

Answer (score 0):

The robospice jar should be in your libs folder as all of its dependencies, please follow the setup instructions on [RoboSpice wiki pages](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki) on Github.